# I can't populate image view using Glide in Firebase recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide, firebaseui

I am trying to populate my Firebase's recycler view with image url. But its not working. Few images are changing on their own. Few aren't displaying. I don't know. May be the image link is not right. Image link are like following:
github.com/GDGVIT/gdgvit.github.io/blob/new-website/members/Shiv.jpg?raw=true,
https://scontent.fdel1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/941872_1155868307766654_5025113179683551097_n.jpg?oh=f83c14f2bc3036ca9be144a08c35b58c&oe=58F02E42,
http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=0BzezVIpuqaxqS3ZzNW56bDJTN0E

Do the size of image in the url matter?

```
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    View view=getView();
    mRef=new Firebase("https://gdg-vit-vellore-af543.firebaseio.com/managementmembers");
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_management_member);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf");
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MemberModel,ManagementMemberFragment.MembersViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<MemberModel,ManagementMemberFragment.MembersViewHolder>(
            MemberModel.class,
            R.layout.card_member,
            ManagementMemberFragment.MembersViewHolder.class,
            mRef.getRef()
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(ManagementMemberFragment.MembersViewHolder membersViewHolder, MemberModel memberModel, int i) {
            membersViewHolder.name.setTypeface(custom_font);
            membersViewHolder.work.setTypeface(custom_font);
            membersViewHolder.githubid.setTypeface(custom_font);
            membersViewHolder.profile_pic.setImageDrawable(null);
            membersViewHolder.name.setText(memberModel.getName());
            membersViewHolder.work.setText(memberModel.getWork());
            membersViewHolder.githubid.setText(memberModel.getGithubid());
            Log.v("From"+"management fragment",memberModel.getProfile_pic());
            Glide.with(getActivity()).load(memberModel.getProfile_pic()).thumbnail(0.4f).error(R.drawable.image_not_found).into(ManagementMemberFragment.MembersViewHolder.profile_pic);
        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public static class MembersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView name,work,githubid;
    static CircleImageView profile_pic;

    public MembersViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        name=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        work=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.member_work);
        githubid=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.member_github_id);
        profile_pic=(CircleImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.member_image);
    }
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: i think some of your link need authentication thats why its not working, upload your images on firebase storage its generate link like "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/b/bucket/o/images%20stars.jpg"  show images using this link. for more details read download file from firebase storage https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files

Answer (score 1):

profile_pic=(CircleImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.member_image);

make sure "member_image" image is of the right xml file. I had same issue i was findingViewId of wrong xml. That was causing this issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a static member to hold any views in a ViewHolder:

```
static CircleImageView profile_pic;
```

Make it an instance member, and refer to it through the ViewHolder reference just like any other view.